# want to Search more then 2 keywords in ASP.net C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i want to Search more then 2 item with one TEXTBOX field using with , Eg. item1,item2.

Result should be shown for both in one gridview i am using SP with one Parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in C#, split your values and pass it to SQL like @astander told,

you can use like,

```
       var Values = Split(Textbox.text) //Textbox.Text.Tostring().Split("Delimeter")

       now you can access array, like

       Values[0]

       Values[1]
```

Pass this to SQL query

Answer (score 1):

In the SP you will have to *split* the value.

Something like

```
--Split
DECLARE @textXML XML
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @delimiter NVARCHAR(5)

SELECT  @data = 'A,B,C',
        @delimiter = ','

SELECT    @textXML = CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(@data, @delimiter, '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML)
SELECT  T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS data
FROM    @textXML.nodes('/d') T(split)
```

Then You can use this in an `WHERE IN` claues or join to the SELECT as a `SUB SELECT` or `CTE statement`

Comment: Can't i do with C#.net Code ?

Comment: Which part do you wish to achieve using C#?